# How to color x and y coordinates in php grid table

Tags: php, colors

I have a grid table. For now, my table x and y coordinates are showing the first letter of a key. I want to change this with the same color for all those coordinates.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
        # Create a temporary holder for our coordinates
        $curr = array( 'x' => $x, 'y' => $y );
        # Add current grid position to the direction we're going
        $curr[ $axis ] += $i;
        # Add the first letter of the key name to the grid
        $grid[ $curr['x'] ][ $curr['y'] ] =  substr( $name, 0, 1 );
    }
```

My output looks like:

```
__________
|r |  |  |
|__|__|__| 
|r |r |  |
|__|__|__|
```

What is best way to change this `$grid[ $curr['x'] ][ $curr['y'] ] =  substr( $name, 0, 1 );` with color? Should I use css or can I do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the same colour for the same letter; so all 'A's would be red?

You could add a list of colours into an array...

```
$color = ['A'=>'FF0000','B'=>'00FF00',...,...]
```

...and get your code to output...

```
"style='background-color: #".$color[$letter]."'"
```

You could even change the hex values for class names and have a nice sass solution, if you're worried about inline styling.

See http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while for more information on that

Comment: So it should look like : `$grid[ $curr['x'] ][ $curr['y'] ] =  $color` or no?